# Stop automatic indenting of tabular in apa6e

Tags: tables, indentation, apa-style

In [apa6e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6e), tabular environments indent automatically. This does not match APA's guidelines.

One can work around this by putting a `\noindent` in front of every `\begin{tabular}{...}` line.

How can I stop the indenting of tabular environments (without using the work-around)?

Example:

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
This appears indented. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the same without loading `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\shorttitle{}    
\let\TAB\tabular
\renewcommand\tabular{\noindent\TAB}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
This appears indented. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `apa6e` class sets the `\RaggedRightParindent` length to 0.5in, which also seems to affect the `tabular` environment. In the following MWE, I use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to add a `\noindent` before every `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\shorttitle{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
This appears indented. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Newsresearcher: it would be helpful for you to report these issues also to the author or `apa6e` so that they can incorporated into future versions.

Comment: @Alan: yes, I am reporting these to the author, and he has been releasing updated versions of apa6e.

Answer (score 2):

If automatic indentation (in the amount of `\RaggedRightParindent`) is supposed to be suppressed for the contents of *all tabular-like environments* -- `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, `longtable`, etc -- and if these environments always occur inside `table` environments, it suffices to issue the following two instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pt}}
```