# Stop automatic indenting of tabular in apa6e with p type

Tags: tables, indentation, apa-style

In apa6e, tabular environments indent automatically. This does not match APA's guidelines.

How can I stop the indenting of tabular environments (without using the work-around)?

The solution in [Stop automatic indenting of tabular in apa6e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22880/stop-automatic-indenting-of-tabular-in-apa6e) does not work

`tex`

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}}
\hline
This appears indented. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `apa6e` class loads `ragged2e`, which redefines `\@arrayparboxrestore` to use `\RaggedRight`. The class does

```
\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0.5in}
```

and the second line is responsible for the indent you see.

Just add

```
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pt}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{apa6e}

\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pt}

\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|}% | just to show the box
\hline
This appears indented. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your preamble, put this, if not already done:

```
\usepackage{array}
```

and use this preamble for your table:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\noindent}p{2cm}}
```